# Dplyr mutate add +1 to column

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to compute for the difference between 2 dates and add + 1 to the result column. I have a large data set. How can I execute this?

```
library(dplyr)

diff <- df %>% mutate(diff = as.character(as.Date(date1, format = "%m/%d/%Y") - as.Date(date2, format = "%m/%d/%Y")))
```

Have already performed subtracting date 1 from date 2 and would like to add + 1 to this column

Comment: Do you want this in the same column? If so, do this inline with your existing `mutate` statement. If an addition column, just add a subsequent `mutate(new_col = diff + days(1))` ...assuming you are using `lubridate` and you are seeking to increment by one day.

Comment: You realize that `+1` works, right? `date1 <- "07/31/1982"; date2 <- "08/01/1982"; as.Date(date1,format = "%m/%d/%Y")-as.Date(date2,format = "%m/%d/%Y")+1`. To add +1 you just type `+1`.

Comment: I made that comment to make the OP consider what they were intending to increment as it was unclear in the question. Being verbose is not an error.

Comment: @kevin.arseneau I was talking to the OP, not you. That's why I didnt @ you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your initial dates look like, but you can get cleaner code with `lubridate` package as Kevin mentions:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

diff<- df %>%
  mutate(diff_plus_one = as.character(ymd(date1) - ymd(date2) + 1)
```

If the dates are in `"%m/%d/%Y"` format, use `mdy` instead of `ymd`, or if they're already `date` objects then don't use anything before.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
diff<- df %>% mutate(diff = difftime(as.Date(date1,format = "%m/%d/%Y"), 
                                     as.Date(date2,format = "%m/%d/%Y")),
                     new_col = as.integer(diff + 1))
```

Notes:

1. `difftime` takes the time difference between the two dates, and returns a `difftime` object
2. Assuming you wanted to add one day to the resulting `diff`, you can just add one and convert the whole thing to integer.
3. The good thing about `difftime` is that you can have different unit of time. So `diff` can actually be in "weeks" or "months"
4. `mutate` lets you use a variable you have just created within the same `mutate` call, so no need a second `mutate` for `new_col=`

Examples:

```
> difftime(as.Date("2017-05-30"),as.Date("2017-05-28"))
Time difference of 2 days

> difftime(as.Date("2018-05-30"),as.Date("2017-05-28"), units = "weeks")
Time difference of 52.42857 weeks

> difftime(as.Date("2018-05-30"),as.Date("2017-05-28"), units = "weeks") %>% as.integer
[1] 52
```